# scikit-learn GridSearchCV does not work properly with random forest

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I have a grid search implementation for random forest models.

```
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=.10, random_state=0)
# A bit performance gains can be obtained from standarization
train_X, test_X = standarize(train_X, test_X)

tuned_parameters = [{
    'n_estimators': [5],
    'criterion': ['mse', 'mae'],
    'random_state': [0]
}]

scores = ['neg_mean_squared_error', 'neg_mean_absolute_error']
for n_fold in [5]:
    for score in scores:
        print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for %s with %d-fold" % (score, n_fold))
        start_time = time.time()
        print()

        # TODO: RandomForestRegressor
        clf = GridSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(verbose=2), tuned_parameters, cv=n_fold,
                           scoring=score, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)
        clf.fit(train_X, train_y)
        ... Rest omitted
```

Before I use it for this grid search, I have used the exact same dataset for many other tasks, so there should not be any problem with the data. In addition, for the test purpose, I first use LinearRegression to see if the entire pipeline goes smoothly, it works. Then I switch to RandomForestRegressor and set a very small number of estimators to test it again. A very strange thing happen them, I'll attach the verbose information. There is a very significant decrease in performance and I don't know what happened. There is no reason to spend 30 minute+ for running one small grid search.

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 2 candidates, totalling 10 fits
[CV] criterion=mse, n_estimators=5, random_state=0 ...................
building tree 1 of 5
[CV] criterion=mse, n_estimators=5, random_state=0 ...................
building tree 1 of 5
[CV] criterion=mse, n_estimators=5, random_state=0 ...................
building tree 1 of 5
[CV] criterion=mse, n_estimators=5, random_state=0 ...................
building tree 1 of 5
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    1.0s remaining:    0.0s
building tree 2 of 5
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    1.0s remaining:    0.0s
building tree 2 of 5
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    1.1s remaining:    0.0s
building tree 2 of 5
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    1.1s remaining:    0.0s
building tree 2 of 5
building tree 3 of 5
building tree 3 of 5
building tree 3 of 5
building tree 3 of 5
building tree 4 of 5
building tree 4 of 5
building tree 4 of 5
building tree 4 of 5
building tree 5 of 5
building tree 5 of 5
building tree 5 of 5
building tree 5 of 5
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    5.0s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    5.0s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    5.0s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    0.2s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    5.0s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    0.3s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    0.3s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    0.2s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    0.8s finished
[CV] .... criterion=mse, n_estimators=5, random_state=0, total=   5.3s
[CV] criterion=mse, n_estimators=5, random_state=0 ...................
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    0.8s finished
[CV] .... criterion=mse, n_estimators=5, random_state=0, total=   5.3s
building tree 1 of 5
[CV] criterion=mae, n_estimators=5, random_state=0 ...................
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    0.9s finished
[CV] .... criterion=mse, n_estimators=5, random_state=0, total=   5.3s
building tree 1 of 5
[CV] criterion=mae, n_estimators=5, random_state=0 ...................
building tree 1 of 5
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    0.9s finished
[CV] .... criterion=mse, n_estimators=5, random_state=0, total=   5.3s
[CV] criterion=mae, n_estimators=5, random_state=0 ...................
building tree 1 of 5
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    1.0s remaining:    0.0s
building tree 2 of 5
building tree 3 of 5
building tree 4 of 5
building tree 5 of 5
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    5.3s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    0.2s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:    0.5s finished
[CV] .... criterion=mse, n_estimators=5, random_state=0, total=   5.6s
[CV] criterion=mae, n_estimators=5, random_state=0 ...................
building tree 1 of 5
```

The above log is printed in a few second, then things seem to be stucked start here...

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:  7.4min remaining:    0.0s
building tree 2 of 5
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:  7.5min remaining:    0.0s
building tree 2 of 5
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:  7.5min remaining:    0.0s
building tree 2 of 5
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:  7.8min remaining:    0.0s
building tree 2 of 5
building tree 3 of 5
building tree 3 of 5
building tree 3 of 5
building tree 3 of 5
building tree 4 of 5
building tree 4 of 5
building tree 4 of 5
building tree 4 of 5
building tree 5 of 5
building tree 5 of 5
building tree 5 of 5
```

It cost more than 20 minutes for these lines.

BTW, for each GridSearchCV run, linear regression cost less than 1 sec.

Do you have any idea why the performance decrease that much?

Any suggestion and comment are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Instead on `n_jobs = -1`, please try with `n_jobs =1` first.

Comment: @VivekKumar That is my first try actually, didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `max_depth` for the RandomForestRegressor.  This should reduce fitting time. By default `max_depth=None`.

For example:

```
tuned_parameters = [{
    'n_estimators': [5],
    'criterion': ['mse', 'mae'],
    'random_state': [0],
    'max_depth': [4],
}]
```

**Edit**: Also, by default `RandomForestRegressor` has `n_jobs=1`.  It will build one tree at a time  with this setting.  Try setting `n_jobs=-1`.

In addition, instead of looping over the `scoring` parameters to `GridSearchCV`, you can specify multiple metrics.  When doing so, you must also specify the metric you want to `GridSearchCV` to select on as the value of `refit`.  Then, you can access all scores in the `cv_results_` dictionary after the fit.

```
    clf = GridSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(verbose=2),tuned_parameters, 
                       cv=n_fold, scoring=scores, refit='neg_mean_squared_error',
                       verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)

    clf.fit(train_X, train_y)
    results = clf.cv_results_
    print(np.mean(results['mean_test_neg_mean_squared_error']))
    print(np.mean(results['mean_test_neg_mean_absolute_error']))
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_multi_metric_evaluation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-multi-metric-evaluation-py

Comment: I'll have a try, but how comes the first several trees are built that fast and the later are screwed...